# Import Library with special character in IronPython

Tags: dll, character, ironpython, .net-assembly

I got a C++.NET library from a colleague with a name like "my-name.dll". Importing in IronPython is not possible since "from my-name import *" is not valid.

If I rename the library to "myname.dll" I get an error that the assembly manifest is missing (HRESULT: 0x80131018). Now I'm not sure wether it is a problem of the wrong name of the accompanying "my-name.lib" file (renaming didn't help) or if there is something different wrong.

I'm not an expert in .NET but as I testet with a VB.NET dll which I built myself (with a proper name) alle worked well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Meanwhile I've seen, that in the very long error message from the line: clr.AddReferenceToFile("my-name.dll") there is also something written like: 'File "mytest.py", line 3, in <module>
IOError: System.IO.IOException: Could not add reference to assembly my-name.dll' so again something with assembly?!

Comment: Now (one day later) I got from my colleague a new version of the dll without special characters. I got: *.dll, *.dll.intermediate.manifest, *.exp and *.lib. Unfortunately I got again: file ... or dependency not found. ... assembly manifest expected ... (it's written in german, but this sould be the proper translation)

Comment: All seems to be related to the issue of managed and unmanaged dll generation. I implemented an example (on my computer in VC++2010) as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235638%28v=vs.80%29.aspx and it worked. I also extended it by a class and all was ok. Now I asked my colleague to do the same at his computer (using VC++2008) and sending me the dll. I will inform you, if I'm successful or not.

Comment: Ok, my colleague finally managed to adapt his configuration as described in the msdn link. Nevertheless, the Debug version of the dll was not applicable because the necessary Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT was not available even with the MS redistributable package for VC++.NET 2008. The Release version of the library finally did it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with the assembly; calling `clr.AddReference('my-name.dll')` should work just fine. One possibility is that your machine is missing the proper VC++ runtime files. Try creating a small VB/C# application and loading the DLL from there.

Also, make sure [the assembly is not blocked](http://blog.jdhardy.ca/2010/09/using-downloaded-ironpython-modules.html).

Comment: OK, two remarks: 1. if I import "my-name.dll" how do I load classes? "from my-name import class"? "my-name" is not a valid Python name, is it? 2. I tried first with a VB program (see above) an all was fine. So basically I'm able to use a dll. I followed your link and I think the dll is not blocked.

Comment: Once the DLL is referenced, you import names from the namespace used in the DLL. .NET namespace names are always valid Python names as well.

Comment: Ok, meanwhile I understood (I hope so) thas if I make my reference like clr.AddReference('my-name.dll') and afterwards from foo import bar, that the foo is NOT the name of the dll but a defined namespace within the dll. If no namespace is available I have to implement only a statement like: import bar